# How to temporarily stop web pages intercepting a right-click?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, context-menu, right-click

Some websites like Google Drive intercept right-clicks and provide their own context menu. This is usually what I want, but sometimes I still want to do a normal, native browser right-click.

Is there any modifier key or something like that to make it so a right-click doesn't trigger a click event on the web page, so it can't show it's context menu?

I want to do this per-click, not by changing a setting somewhere.

If there are different techniques depending on browser/OS, please list them.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works with other web pages, but on Google Drive I use Shift + RightClick to get the "normal" context menu.

Comment: @Ellesa you saved my life. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

There seem to be two “Allow Right Click” extensions. The one that Bryan mentioned (with a dash) is bad; it has too many ads on by default.

A better extension is [*Allow RightClick*](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/odgmhaimkkjbnpmnpbgemphpcedcbbfd) (note the lack of a dash) by Ergün Adatepe. It seems much better—no ads. It is 2 years old (2010), but seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in way to prevent pages from intercepting the right click. There is currently an issue ([issue 30153](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=30153)) requesting that there be a way to manage Javascript permissions, but it has been open since December 11, 2009, and they still haven't implemented it. *Sigh.*

This means that the only way to re-enable the context menu is to use an extension. Fortunately, there is an extension that does such a thing. [Allow Right-Click](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hompjdfbfmmmgflfjdlnkohcplmboaeo) appears to be what you want; from the description, *Allow Right-Click*...

> **Re-enable the possibility to use the context menu on sites that overrides it.**
>
> This extension re-enables the context menu.
>
> Indeed, many sites prohibit the right-click on images, pretending to protect their
>   content. I think it is illegitimate.

This extension is ad supported though. Fortunately, it appears that you can disable it in the settings.

Comment: *> it has been open since December 11, 2009, and they still haven't implemented it. Sigh.*   Actually, that Chrome issue was marked as *WontFix* on Jul 9, 2010, so it *won’t* be implemented. *double sigh*   However, they have since (more or less) implemented an [API](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=71067) that allows extensions to affect content settings (JavaScript).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the right-click handler is disabled, it may be simple or difficult:

- You may be able to simply right-click again while the custom context-menu is still open (e.g., on Flickr photos)
- You may need to hold down the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key (e.g., in Google Drive)
- You may even have to resort to using JavaScript to actually edit the page and strip the handlers (this would not be a per-click modification)

Answer (score 0):

On a Mac, hold down the <kbd>Command</kbd> key while you right-click. For me, this overrides the hijacked right-click of many WYSIWYG web editors allowing you to access the OS's built-in spell check.